# How to get the offsetLeft/offsetTop of the <g id="iqaluit"> and <circle id="circle"> elements on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, ecmascript-6, html5-canvas

How to get **offsetLeft/offsetTop** of ****<g id="iqaluit">** and **<circle id="circle">** elements in javascript.
I tried this: but it gives an error TypeError: bar is null.

JS

```
let bar = document.getElementById('iqaluit');
console.log(bar.offsetLeft, bar.offsetTop)
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');
console.log(circle.offsetLeft, circle.offsetTop);
```

HTML

```
<div class="section-map">
    <canvas class="svgfix__canvas" width="500" height="488"> </canvas>
    <svg id="MAP" data-name="MAP" data-province="MAP" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1100 1072.93">
        <g id="City_Labels_Canada" data-name="City Labels Canada">

            <g id="iqaluit" data-name="Iqaluit" data-province="nunavut" class="city nohover">

                <circle id="circle" cx="839.32" cy="390.34" r="3.1"></circle>

                <text x="847" y="394" data-name="Iqaluit" class="en de fr es">Iqaluit</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: May be you are trying to access it before dom loading. 
`window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('All assets are loaded')
       let bar =  document.getElementById('iqaluit');
console.log(bar.offsetLeft, bar.offsetTop)
let circle = document.getElementById('circle');
console.log(circle.offsetLeft, circle.offsetTop);
})`

Note : SVG elements doesn't support offset left and top.

Comment: Yes, it seems that in the case of the *<circle>* tag, the problem is this "SVG elements doesn't support offset left and top.".  But is the *<g>* tag also considered an svg element?

Comment: yes because g and cricle both tags inside svg [Read More about this ](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetleft).


you can try this [Element.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dio, you're on the right track. The svg elements do not support the properties you are looking for but you can access the elements, just a little differently from how you attempted, with the document. See below.

Also, the suggestion from @Syed Qasim Ahmed provides an object, but I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve with offsetLeft/offsetTop, so I can't say if it's equivalent or not.

```js
const map = document.getElementById('MAP');
const bar = map?.querySelector('#iqaluit');

/**
 * You can see the available
 * methods and properties
 * with a for in loop
 */
 
if (bar) {
  for (let i in bar) {
    console.log('what is i?', i);
    console.log('what is bar[i]?', bar[i]);
  }

  const getBoundingClientRect = bar.getBoundingClientRect();

  console.log({ getBoundingClientRect });
}
```

```html
<div class="section-map">
    <canvas class="svgfix__canvas" width="500" height="488"> </canvas>
    <svg id="MAP" data-name="MAP" data-province="MAP" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1100 1072.93">
        <g id="City_Labels_Canada" data-name="City Labels Canada">

            <g id="iqaluit" data-name="Iqaluit" data-province="nunavut" class="city nohover">

                <circle id="circle" cx="839.32" cy="390.34" r="3.1"></circle>

                <text x="847" y="394" data-name="Iqaluit" class="en de fr es">Iqaluit</text>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
</div>
```